# Using "the" in this sentence: "I won the first place at the tournament"

Tags: articles, determiners, zero-article

Here is the sentence where I am confused as to whether I should put **the** or not:

> "I won first place at the tournament"

**OR**

> "I won the first place at the tournament"

Which one is correct according to American/United States English?

Here's a Google NGram regarding usage - http://bit.ly/20LmDri

Comment: What are the relative frequencies in a Google search? In Ngrams "won first place at/in" and "won the first place at/in"?

Comment: @FF I'd guess that the situation changes between 'won [the] first place in/at' and 'won [the] first prize in/at'. But I think OP should find the data.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Here's the Ngram - http://bit.ly/20LmDri

Comment: And can you make a deduction as to which it's probably better to use? And whether the other is absolutely unacceptable?

Comment: "I won the first place at the tournament" is wrong and would seem like broken English spoken by a foreign speaker.

Answer (score 2):

The first one makes sense, but if you want to use "the" you could say "I won the first place prize/spot/position at the tournament"

Comment: 'Makes sense' and 'is idiomatic' are unfortunately distant cousins in English.