# some confusing expressions with number

Tags: word-usage, american-english, ambiguity, numbers, adjective-order

When I want to express one of the series in harry potter,
which one is better?
ex) Third episode is my favorite among whole series.

Third episode/
episode three

Are all of them can be used?
If not, what is the problem with them?

One more question...
In a subway linemap, what is the exact way to express line?

line one = the most common used
first line (is it also possible?/ then how about line first?)

I want someone to distinguish their differences as I don't have intuition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A question about using definite article with ordinal numbers: "content with third place" or "content with the third place"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102607/a-question-about-using-definite-article-with-ordinal-numbers-content-with-thir). Basically, *I watched episode three* is fine, but you need to include the definite article if you use the "ordinal" form *I watched **the third** episode*.

Comment: I mean the order of those words. the third episode is the same as episode three? Do they mean the same?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing. But to repeat myself, when you say *I saw episode 3* there's no article, but you must include the definite article when you say *I saw **the** third episode*.